# What's $mask in file_scan_directory() to find all png files?

Tags: 7, files

I try to find all png files in a directory inside my module using this code with no success:

```
$banks = file_scan_directory(drupal_get_path('module', 'order').'/images/gateways', '/^.*\png$/');
```

What mask should I used for getting all png files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following mask should work for you:

`'/.*\.png$/'`

Comment: Might want to make that `'/.*.png$/i'` so the case isn't matched

Comment: I used `/png$/`, but your is better, thanks.